# I have a do until loop, that uses a boolean and an input box. Trying to get a str variable from the input loop

Tags: vba, excel

In Visual Basics I  have a do until loop to to make sure the date is entered in a correct way. How can I take the user input in the in put box and save it as a date variable?

```
Private Sub cmdbtn3_Click()

'create a booleanvariable
Dim blDone As Boolean

'ask for there name
strName = InputBox("Please Enter Your Name", "Step 1")

'create a do while not because we want a repeat until blDone is True
Do While Not blDone

    'set the value of the input box with the product list equal to the boolean
    'ask for the date of the start, have a do loop until date1
    blDone = InputBox("Please Enter the Estimated Starting Date of CU" & vbNewLine & "Example 05/24/2014") Like "##/##/####"


    'Create a msg that explains what the input must be
    If Not blDone Then MsgBox "the input didn't match the pattern '01/23/2014' where:" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'01' must bethe month" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'23' must be the date" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'2014' must be the year"

'I need to save the value of the date as

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Store input and then do comparison on that.  If `dateInput` is set as `Date` type, then your check fails because `01/01/2000` is changed to `1/1/2000`.  I got around this by capturing it in `Variant` for the check and then converting it and storing in `dateOutput` at the end.

```
Private Sub cmdbtn3_Click()

'create a booleanvariable
Dim blDone As Boolean, dateInput As Variant, dateOutput As Date

'ask for there name
strName = InputBox("Please Enter Your Name", "Step 1")

'create a do while not because we want a repeat until blDone is True
Do While Not blDone

    'set the value of the input box with the product list equal to the boolean
    'ask for the date of the start, have a do loop until date1
    dateInput = InputBox("Please Enter the Estimated Starting Date of CU" & vbNewLine & "Example 05/24/2014")

    blDone = dateInput Like "##/##/####"

    'Create a msg that explains what the input must be
    If Not blDone Then MsgBox "the input didn't match the pattern '01/23/2014' where:" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'01' must bethe month" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'23' must be the date" _
                              & vbNewLine & vbTab & "'2014' must be the year"

'I need to save the value of the date as

Loop

dateOutput = CDate(dateInput)

End Sub
```